# Xamarin Forms: Back to option is covering the app layout when opening the app from test flight or by search

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

Following is one of the screenshots of my ios app when I open it from the test flight.

[image]

Here **<- testflight** option is covering my search box. Have the same problem for all the pages top portion.

This problem also happens when opening the app by searching. When open app by searching **<-search** option is showing on top.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi ,every time from TestFlight open is like this? It seems like UI bug from Apple.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes every time showing like this, always covering the app UI. Is there any way to fix this from app side?

Comment: First you can have a try with other devices to check whether have this phenomenon . If always occurs, can submit to Apple support .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Ok I will try and update here.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi I tried on iphone7, iPhone se and iPhone x. Problem is only on the iPhone x.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT But other apps are working fine on that iPhone x. Only this app have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying ,So problem is just showed in like iPhone x device.Maybe it's the SafeArea problem,you can first try Prateek's answer.If not works, I will try to share another method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set safe area to true for iOS

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Safe Area"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <StackLayout>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout